# JAXB class generation with external schema reference

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I'm generating JAXB classes using a schema which imports an external schema. This external schema is in the same folder with the source schema. Classes are generated without any errors and after generation there two packages one for imported schema and the other for the schema that imports it. However, at the point of element reference to the imported schema, more precisely at the line:

**@XmlElementRef(name = "elementName", namespace = "http://importedSchema/url", type = JAXBElement.class)**

I get an error as:

**"No XML element decl in the XML registry matching the namespace 'http://importedSchema/url' and name 'elementName'.**"

The element referenced with the name "elementName" is in the other package. I can see its class and its also in ObjectFactory.java but unfortunately, I get this error.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

N.b.

**Schema Root Tag:**

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://mySchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://mySchema" xmlns:es="http://importedSchema/url">
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="ESchema.xsd" namespace="http://importedSchema/url">
```

**Element Reference:**

```
<xsd:complexType name="myType">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element ref="es:elementName"></xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```